# How to sum multiple amounts from Sheet1 to Sheet2 using Dates as idenfier?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

I would like to get the sum of the amount in cells from Sheet1 based on their dates then output onto Sheet2. I have tried searching but to no avail. I have no idea what code to use. I tried this formula `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(H13,Sheet1!J:BR,IF((Sheet1!J:BR=H13),ROW(A:A),100),FALSE)))` that I found online but I doesn't do the job.

Comment: I don't think I follow your sheet. Can you explain what the dates in black represent and how they are related to column I? If you could share a copy of your sheet that would be pretty helpful too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note

To not over complicate this we'll fill the table with "Due Date" header to be used in the filter functions later on like so `=$A$1`.

[image]

### Sloution 01 - On one go

> **Paste** this in Sheet2 cell `B2`

```
=SUM(FILTER(INDEX(QUERY({ FLATTEN(FILTER( Sheet1!$B:$F,Sheet1!$A:$A="Due Date")), FLATTEN(FILTER( Sheet1!$B$1:$F,Sheet1!$A:$A<>"",Sheet1!$A:$A<>"Due Date")) }, " Select * Where Col1 is not null "),,2),INDEX(QUERY({ FLATTEN(FILTER( Sheet1!$B:$F,Sheet1!$A:$A="Due Date")), FLATTEN(FILTER( Sheet1!$B$1:$F,Sheet1!$A:$A<>"",Sheet1!$A:$A<>"Due Date")) }, " Select * Where Col1 is not null "),,1)=B1))
```

[image]

### Sloution 02 - Helper table

> To genrate a normalized table paste this formula.

```
= QUERY({ FLATTEN(FILTER( B:F,A:A="Due Date")), FLATTEN(FILTER( B1:F,A:A<>"",A:A<>"Due Date")) }, " Select * Where Col1 is not null ")
```

[image]

> And **Paste** this formula to refrence the normalized tabel

```
=SUM(FILTER('Normlized table'!$I$2:$I,'Normlized table'!$H$2:$H=B1))
```

[image]

Comment: Your solutions would've worked but I forgot to mention I have like hundreds of rows. Is there a better way to do it? I'll add a screenshot of the actual sheet1

@Osm

Comment: @Oloap It's been updated, make sure to name the tables header "Due Date" .